# Governance plan - SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Can I get link for a short & sweet material on governance plan?

Comment: A short and sweet governance plan is an oxymoron. I cannot tell you the number of times I have seen people getting into SharePoint that make this mistake. But at least you know that governance exists! Deploying SharePoint and not putting any thought or enough thought into governance and information architecture is what gives SharePoint a bad reputation in most cases.

Comment: While the actual "plan" may be complicated, I do recommend you have a way to summarize the significant portions to present to users.  If you throw a 100+ page plan at them and there was not one before it will fail.  You need to engage your users and make it digestible in small portions for them. It helps if you already have some type of IM policies (Network, Email, etc) that you can build off of (users will already have an understanding of the requirements and expectations).

Comment: You have received two very useful answers. Don't forget to accept one of them.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry but "short and sweet" doesn't exist when it comes to SharePoint. Here facts rule over opinion and ideas. The reason is that SharePoint effect many businesses, and in doing so its about money. Having a "short and sweet" governance plan will put you out of work in no time. To avoid this, start with this white paper:

> This white paper focuses on what we call the “front end” of the SharePoint environment – the business aspect of governance - the areas that effect business users. This white paper uses a fictitious company named Contoso to provide guidance for the necessary governance planning and implementation of SharePoint Server 2010.

[SharePoint 2010 Governance Planning (white paper)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848257%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Additional Resources Related to Governance**

[Plan Governance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263341%28office.12%29) (specifically for 2007 but still relevant)

[Essential SharePoint 2010: Overview, Governance, and Planning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321700759)

[Practical SharePoint 2013 Governance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430248874)

[Information Architecture for the World Wide Web: Designing Large-Scale Web Sites, 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596527349)

[Card Sorting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933820020) (a practical look at a fundamental [IA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_architecture) tool)

Comment: Benny, I have reached my vote limit for the day so I am going to have to wait until tomorrow for an upvote. But I am going to add some additional reading material I think could help on this topic. I'm making it even less short and sweet, but that's the reality of governance.

Comment: @RobertKaucher Thank you! I'll make sure to give this courtesy back your way. BR

Comment: @RobertKaucher Referencing my favorite Card Sorting book by Donna Spencer, make me wonder... Are you an Information Architect, like me? :-)

Comment: No, sir. Not officially. But it is certainly an area of concern for me and I have to put on the IA hat in my department sometimes.

Comment: Officially and officially. IA is more of a sixth sense, a path to user experience. Great that you have the opportunity to do IA work!

Answer (score 3):

Simply to add to other participants already very wisely expressed, do not try to swallow an elephant, rather start simple. I strongly recommand read these series to get you started http://kjellsj.blogspot.ch/2010/05/minimal-governance-plan-sharepoint.html

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers if you found it useful. Giving and receiving reputation is what drives the community!

Answer (score 0):

Check out :

1) [Business-Centric Portal Strategy for running successful Sharepoint Projects](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2014/01/23/business-centric-sharepoint-strategy/) and 2) 
[Effective Sharepoint Governance : A must for Sustaining the Success](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2013/06/17/sharepoint-governance/)